# Is this equation valid $\gamma b^{e \log_b{n+e}} = \gamma b^e + n^e$,?

Tags: analysis

While reading a script I found this equation:

$\gamma b^{e \log_b{n+e}} = \gamma b^e + n^e$

and i cannot figure out how the author did this. I'd appreciate a step-by step equation for this equation.

Comment: Looks wrong to me. Shouldn't you have a multiplication there instead of a sum on the right hand side?

Comment: @Sim Is it $\log (n+e)$ or $\log (n)+e$?

Comment: @GitGud no brackets used, but maybe due to convenience

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could be, but not in the equation I got,  it could be an error though

Comment: @Sim ****ing analysts. Either way it seems wrong. It's "almost" right if it is $\log (n)+e$.

Comment: @GitGud then treat it that way, like I said it could be $\log_b(n) + e and no brackets were used due to convenience (and for confusion)

Comment: @Sim In that case Jyrki Lahtonen did that just above your comment.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen seems reasonable, I'd accept that as an answer, probably a typo or so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the definition of the logarithm 
$b^{\log_b n}=n$, so following the usual rules of powers of power: $b^{e\log_b n}=(b^{\log_b n})^e=n^e$. Another rule about powers is $b^{x+y}=b^x\cdot b^y$, so altogether we get $b^{e\log_b n+e}=b^{e\log_bn}\cdot b^e=n^e\cdot b^e$.

Therefore it should read
$$\gamma b^{e\log_b n+e}=\gamma b^e\cdot n^e,$$
and it looks like a multiplication sign was accidentally converted to a plus sign.